# Can you port elementary's default apps to Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, code

So is it possible to port apps like Scratch to a stock version of Ubuntu and if so where should I look to get started?

As far as I can tell it should be possible since Scratch uses GTK which works just fine on Ubuntu, it is written in Vala which compiles to C. The only problem is that it uses some libraries of ElementaryOS.

ElementaryOS is based of Ubuntu so I dont see why this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

ElementaryOS uses a framework called Granite in which all its apps heavily relay on. If you manage to install the Granite Framework and its dependencies on Ubuntu (GNOME) yes, theoretically you could have eOS apps on Ubuntu.